# Asymetrical data fitting function

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression, sigmoid

Please can you help me ? I have non linear data that fit in an asymmetrical sigmoid function. So I've generated a sigmoid function. And I've used that in the curve_fit function to generate a beta1 and beta2. But the sigmoid function that I have accepts only one input variable. Is there a sigmoid function that accepts multiple input variables ? Here is my code for the train_test_split, the sigmoid and the curve_fit functions :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('Montant TLPE', axis=1).values, df['Montant TLPE'].values, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)

def sigmoid(x, Beta_1, Beta_2):
    y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Beta_1*(x-Beta_2)))
    return y

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train))
print(" beta_1 = %f, beta_2 = %f" % (popt[0], popt[1]))
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: check out [the generalized logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function)

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple input variables", if `x` is a list?

Comment: x is a multiple column dataframe with normalized values

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the scatter plot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMOEd.png)